# How do I fix the responsive css for iframes

Tags: css, iframe, responsive

I am trying to embed two iframes side-by-side and have them resize with screen width. On screens smaller than 500px, I want the second iframe to "wrap" below the first, and both expand to nearly full width. What actually happens is on screens less than about 488px, the second iframe drops down but both stay the same width and stay in the same relative position (the second iframe stays to the right)

Here is my code so far:

```css
.vimeo-wrapper {
        max-width: 1200px;
        position: relative;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }

    .vimeo-standard {
        float: left;
        height: 470px;
        width: 75%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin: 1px;
    }
    .vimeo-chatbox {
        float: right;
        height: 470px;
        width: 24%;
        border: 1px solid #000;
        margin: 1px;
    }
    iframe {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }


    *@media (max-width:750px) and (min-width:700px){
        .vimeo-standard {
            float: left;
            height: 294px;
            width: 74%;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            margin: 0 auto;
       }
       .vimeo-chatbox {
           float: right;
           height: 294px;
           width: 24%;
           border: 1px solid #000;
           margin: 0 auto;
       }
       iframe {
        width: 90%;
        height: 100%;
        }
    }
    
    *@media (max-width:699px) and (min-width:600px){
        .vimeo-standard {
            float: left;
            height: 252px;
            width: 74%;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            margin: 0 auto;
       }
       .vimeo-chatbox {
           float: right;
           height: 252px;
           width: 24%;
           border: 1px solid #000;
           margin: 0 auto;
       }
       iframe {
        width: 90%;
        height: 100%;
        }
    }
    *@media (max-width:599px) and (min-width:500px){
        .vimeo-standard {
            float: left;
            height: 210px;
            width: 74%;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            margin: 0 auto;
       }
       .vimeo-chatbox {
           float: right;
           height: 210px;
           width: 24%;
           border: 1px solid #000;
           margin: 0 auto;
       }
       iframe {
        width: 90%;
        height: 100%;
        }
    }
    *@media (max-width:499px) {
        .vimeo-standard {
            float: none;
            height: 200px;
            width: 100%;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            margin: 2px auto;
            padding-bottom: 10px;
       }
       .vimeo-chatbox {
           float: none;
           width: 100%;
           height: 200px;
           border: 1px solid #000;
           margin: 2px auto;
           padding-top: 5px;
       }
       iframe {
        width: 90%;
        height: 100%;
        }
    }

    .clearfix:before,
    .clearfix:after {
        content: " "; /* 1 */
        display: table; /* 2 */
    }

    .clearfix:after {
        clear: both;
    }
```

```html
<div class="vimeo-wrapper">
    <div class="vimeo-video vimeo-standard">
        <iframe src="/*test url */" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" seamless>
        </iframe>
    </div>
    <div class="vimeo-chat vimeo-chatbox">
        <iframe src="/*test url 2*/" 
            frameborder="0" seamless>
        </iframe>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code actually looks fine, the problem is the * characters you've put before your @media queries (this isn't valid CSS). Removing them makes everything work for me:

```css
.vimeo-wrapper {
  max-width: 1200px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.vimeo-standard {
  float: left;
  height: 470px;
  width: 75%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1px;
}

.vimeo-chatbox {
  float: right;
  height: 470px;
  width: 24%;
  border: 1px solid #000;
  margin: 1px;
}

iframe {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

@media (max-width:750px) and (min-width:700px) {
  .vimeo-standard {
    float: left;
    height: 294px;
    width: 74%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .vimeo-chatbox {
    float: right;
    height: 294px;
    width: 24%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  iframe {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:699px) and (min-width:600px) {
  .vimeo-standard {
    float: left;
    height: 252px;
    width: 74%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .vimeo-chatbox {
    float: right;
    height: 252px;
    width: 24%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  iframe {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:599px) and (min-width:500px) {
  .vimeo-standard {
    float: left;
    height: 210px;
    width: 74%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  .vimeo-chatbox {
    float: right;
    height: 210px;
    width: 24%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 0 auto;
  }
  iframe {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

@media (max-width:499px) {
  .vimeo-standard {
    float: none;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 2px auto;
    padding-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .vimeo-chatbox {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #000;
    margin: 2px auto;
    padding-top: 5px;
  }
  iframe {
    width: 90%;
    height: 100%;
  }
}

.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
  content: " ";
  /* 1 */
  display: table;
  /* 2 */
}

.clearfix:after {
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div class="vimeo-wrapper">
  <div class="vimeo-video vimeo-standard">
    <iframe src="/*test url */" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen mozallowfullscreen allowfullscreen="allowfullscreen" seamless>
        </iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="vimeo-chat vimeo-chatbox">
    <iframe src="/*test url 2*/" frameborder="0" seamless>
        </iframe>
  </div>
</div>
```